# How to exctract java sources from a multi maven modules project

Tags: java

I have a parent maven project with several subprojects.

I want to be able to make a clean copy of all the source code of these project. So generate a jar file that include the parent project with his subproject.

For that i look at the Apache Maven Source Plugin but I only manage to generate a source code jar by subproject (when I only want one independante Jar that include all project).

Is there a way to do that easily with this plugin or by an other way ?

I also try to use the export functionality in Eclipse but I have to filter by hand all files that I don't want (.project, .classpath). There was a filter to tell only which kind of file include but what i would need is a filter to tell which kind of file don't include.

Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GIT, you can try on the root of the project (on branch develop for example) :

```
git archive --format=zip develop > sources.jar
```

You will have an archive (zip, renamed to jar, format) with your sources.

Is it sufficient for you ?

Comment: I'm using git but I want to exclude some files that are not in the gitignore.

Comment: Add a .gitattributes file on your repo. For each line : `[FILE or FOLDER] export-ignore`. See [Git documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) (Files and directories with the attribute export-ignore won’t be added to archive files.)